# Tag merge candidates: [particle] and [particles]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Suggest moving [particle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particle) into [particles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particles) and copying the wiki over.

[image]